# Add class to nth of an element found on full page instead within a parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, element, addclass

I'm trying to add classes to the "nth" of a particular element - regardless of where it falls on the page. A simplified version of my html is:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12"><section class="subsection"></section></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><section class="subsection"></section></div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><section class="subsection"></section></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><section class="subsection"></section></div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><section class="subsection"></section></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><section class="subsection"></section></div>
</div>
etc...
```

And this is what I'm using for my jQuery:

```
$( ".subsection:nth-of-type(4n+1)" ).addClass("first-row");

$( ".subsection:nth-of-type(4n+2)" ).addClass("second-row");

$( ".subsection:nth-of-type(4n+3)" ).addClass("third-row");

$( ".subsection:nth-of-type(4n)" ).addClass("fourth-row");
```

As predicted, it's recognizing each .subsection as the first-child, but I'm trying to get this as the finished output:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12"><section class="subsection first-row"></section></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><section class="subsection second-row"></section></div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><section class="subsection third-row"></section></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><section class="subsection fourth-row"></section></div>
</div>
<div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><section class="subsection first-row"></section></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"><section class="subsection second-row"></section></div>
</div>
etc...
```

Anyone know how I can accomplish this? I've also tried nth-child, .filter(), section[class="subsection"], and a few other ways of approaching this, but haven't been able to figure this out.

I feel like this post sounds confusing. Let me know if you need me to clarify... :)

--- EDITED: to show that it needs to loop every time it hits "4n" nth-of-type

Comment: Doing a loop here works far better. Select the subsections and loop through them using `each`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `$('section.subsection')` and then either use `.eq()` or `.each`. See this fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/0q3gk194/

Edit: For repeating every 4, use `.each()` and switch on the provided index modulo 4. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0q3gk194/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to have it loop back around when it's divisible by the number (4n+1, 4n+2, etc.)... So let's say there's a 5th .subsection on the page, that would start back at first-child and get a class of "first-row." With your method, I'm targeting each one individually. I'll edit my original post to give you a better idea.

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes, all it takes a fresh set of eyes to approach the problem at a different angle. :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery you can grab the `nth-child` of a specific selector using `eq()`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.col-sm-12').filter(function(i, item){
        if(i != 0 && (i+3)%3 == 0) {
          $(item).css( 'background-color', 'red');
        }
    });
});
```

Will make every 4th `.col-sm-12` element have a red background.

Here's the [full demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/qgepz7nu/).

Comment: The guy who commented above you mentioned a similar method, but it's only targeting the specific element - I need it to loop back around, so if there's a 5th .subsection on the page, it'll start back at 1 and get a class of "first-row." I'm updating my original post to explain it better.